# Inserting array values and other from values of a form into two different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'am trying to insert data from a form into two different tables. Here's what I'am doing:-

```php
<?php

$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","store_records");
if($mysqli->connect_error)
    die("Database connection failed ".$mysqli->connect_error);

$query = "insert into bill_details(date,invoice_no,balance) values('".$_POST['p_date']."','".$_POST['invoice_no']."','".$_POST['balance']."')";
if($mysqli->query($query))
{
    $cquery="";
    for ( $i=0;$i<$_POST['row_numbers'];$i++) 
    {
        $cquery .= "insert into bill_records(item_name,qty,pack,batch,expiry,mrp,rate,vat,discount,invoice_no) values('".$_POST['item_name'][$i]."','".$_POST['qty'][$i]."','".$_POST['pack'][$i]."','".$_POST['batch'][$i]."','".$_POST['expiry'][$i]."','".$_POST['mrp'][$i]."','".$_POST['rate'][$i]."','".$_POST['vat'][$i]."','".$_POST['discount'][$i]."','".$_POST['invoice_no']."');";
    }
    if($mysqli->multi_query($cquery))
        echo "Records Saved";
    else
        echo "Failed to save product records";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed To save Records";
}
?>
```

Now, data from the  first query is getting stored into **bill_details** table. but the array values are not getting stored. I cant figure out what am I doing wrong with my code. I wanna know how can i solve this problem and use the **invoice_no** as reference key for both the tables.

Here are the structure of both the database tables..

[bill_details table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FViHx.png)

[bill_records table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgenM.png)

Comment: This code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: i m well aware of that mate, once this code works i'll fix it.

Comment: `if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) { echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error; }`

Comment: it worked.. i was silly, didn't thought of echoing whats the problem..   thanks a lot pal.. :)

Comment: sure :) you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this. Hope it works. :)

<?php

$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","store_records");
if($mysqli->connect_error)
die("Database connection failed ".$mysqli->connect_error);

$query = "insert into bill_details(date,invoice_no,balance) values('".$_POST['p_date']."','".$_POST['invoice_no']."','".$_POST['balance']."')";
if($mysqli->query($query))
{
    $cquery="";
    for ( $i=0;$i<$_POST['row_numbers'];$i++) 
    {
        $cquery .= "insert into bill_records(item_name,qty,pack,batch,expiry,mrp,rate,vat,discount,invoice no) values('".$_POST['item_name'][$i]."','".$_POST['qty'][$i]."','".$_POST['pack'][$i]."','".$_POST['batch'][$i]."','".$_POST['expiry'][$i]."','".$_POST['mrp'][$i]."','".$_POST['rate'][$i]."','".$_POST['vat'][$i]."','".$_POST['discount'][$i]."','".$_POST['invoice_no']."');";
        if(!($mysqli->query($cquery)))
            die("failed to save");
    }
}
else{
    echo "Failed To save Records";
}

?>
```